# HandBrakeCLI and CoreAudio

Tags: video, encoding, encode, video-processing, video-encoding

Could you tell me how to use HandbrakeCLI with coreaudio?

Found this unapplied patch http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/UnappliedPatches#coreAudio
but dont know how to build it myself on osx-snowleopard..

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... updated my GUI, but not my CLI...

Works now! (in 0.9.4!)